# Dealing with missing values

Tags: python, machine-learning, missing-data

I have two data sets, training and test set. 
If I have NA values in the training set but not in the test set, I usually drop the rows (if they are few) in the training set and that's all.

But now, I got a lot of NA values in both sets, so I have dropped the features which got lot most of NA values, and I was wondering what to do now.

Should I just drop the same features in the test set and impute the rest missing values?

Is there any other technique I could use to preprocess the data?

Can Machine Learning algorithms like Logistic Regression, Decision Trees or Neural Netwroks handle missing values?

The data sets come from a Kaggle competition so I can't do the preprocessing before splitting the data

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends very much on the data but perhaps see my introductory answer on [Azure Machine Learning Studio and its' Clean Missing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53242464/6241235) and look up related resources. You can run Python and R through this studio as well.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not so easy to answer, because it depends on the type of NA values.

Are the NA values due to some random reason? Or is there a reason they are missing (no matching multiple choice answer in a survey or maybe something people would not like to answer)

For the first, it would be fine to use a simple imputation strategy, so that you can fit your model on the data. Thereby, I mean something like mean imputation or sampling from an estimated probability distribution. Or even sampling values at random. Note, that if you simply take the mean of the existing values, you change the statistics of the dataset, i.e. you reduce the standard deviation. You should keep that in mind when choosing your model.

For the second, you will have to apply you domain knowledge to find good fill values.

Regarding your last question: if you want to fill the values with a machine learning model, you may use the other features of the dataset and implicitly assume a dependency between the missing feature and the other features. Depending on the model you will later use for prediction, you may not benefit from the intermediate estimation.

I hope this helps, but the correct answer really depends on the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The data comes from a Kaggle competition so I actually don't know if the values are due to a random reason.

Answer (score 1):

In general, machine learning algorithms do not cope well with missing values (for mostly good reasons, as it is not known why they are missing or what it means to be missing, which could even be different for different observations).

Good practice would be to do the preprocessing before the split between training and test sets (are your training and test data truly random subsets of the data, as they should be?) and ensure that both sets are treated identically.

There is a plethora of ways to deal with your missing data and it depends strongly on the data, as well as on your goals, which are the better ways. Feel free to get in contact if you need more specific advice.

Comment: Is there anyb log or article which I can go looking for info? I only know imputation to deal with missing data.

Comment: There are basically only two ways to deal with missing data, if your ML algorithm can't handle them: ignore the corresponding observations (or features) or do some kind of imputation, of which there are many (many of which in turn depend on machine learning models).

For this, as well a for many other Python/ML topics, the book by Jake VanderPlas, Data Science Handbook, is a fantastic resource, and it is fully available as ipynb notebooks on github. The section you are looking for is: https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/03.04-Missing-Values.ipynb